# Tkinter Listbox based on attribute not displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

Calling this class works and the workout name is always shown properly. However, when the class is called from another document, the listbox with the different exercises (which are determined based on the workout name by the 'findUebungen' function) is not displayed at all. Printing 'self.__uebungsliste' shows that the right list is still saved in the variable. Is it an issue with listboxCV?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from user import *

class Workout(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.root.geometry('1440x1024')
        self.root.title('Workout Screen')
        self.__name = name
        self.__uebungsListe = []
        self.findUebungen()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.mainloop()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.nameTraining = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.nameTraining.config(font=("Courier", 40))
        self.nameTraining.place(x=384, y=126, width=800, height=71)
        self.nameTraining['anchor'] = 'w'
        self.nameTraining['text'] = self.__name + ' - Workout'

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.root)
        self.listbox.config(font=("Arial", 16))
        self.listbox.place(x=200, y=320, width=340, height=200)
        self.listboxCV = tk.StringVar()
        self.listboxCV.set(self.__uebungsListe)
        self.listbox['listvariable'] = self.listboxCV 
        pass

    def findUebungen(self):
        if self.__name == "Warm Up":
            self.__uebungsListe = ['1. Hampelmänner', '2. Butt Kicks', '3. Lunges', '4. Squats', '5. Mountain Climbers', '6. Arme kreisen']
        elif self.__name == "Kraft":
            self.__uebungsListe = ['1. Plank', '2. Side Plank', '3. Sit Ups', '4. Liegestütze', '5. Curls', '6. Face Pulls']
        else:
            self.__uebungsListe = ['1. Muskeln ausschütteln', '2. Fasernpistole nutzen', '3. Ausrollen auf Blackroll']
        print(self.__uebungsListe)
```

Comment: You are most likely calling `Tk()` more than once in your program.  That causes all sorts of problems, such as `StringVar`s not working.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: If you replace tk.Tk() with tk.Toplevel() in Line 8, there are no problems anymore. Thanks for your help @jasonharper

Comment: I ran your code. And it displayed 1. Muskeln ausschütteln ',' 2. Fasernpistole nutzen ',' 3. Ausrollen auf Blackroll in the listbox. Actually, I don't understand what you want to do.